# can't get bootstrap tooltip to work in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in a partial in my rails app :
http://jsfiddle.net/VYeqm/2/

Its working fine in the fiddle but I can't figure out why its not working in my app. I checked the loaded resources with web inspector in the browser and its loading bootstrap-tooltip.js. (bootstrap-tooltip.js v2.0.3). Do I need a newer version? I've also tried moving the script into the application.js file and either way I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Any idea what might be causing this? I'm stumped. Thanks!

UPDATE:

new error is :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'
```

Comment: jsfiddle sometimes have invisible characters in their editor, retype your code and try it again. The fiddle you posted has one at the very end of the JavaScript section, if you put you cursor to the very end and press backspace nothing seems to happen, this is an illegal token being deleted.

Comment: Thanks! My error has now been upgraded to : Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tooltip'

Comment: did you include the bootstrap library before your code.

Comment: Are you including the bootstrap style sheet?

Comment: I ended u directly including the bootstrap.js remote link in my application.html header for now instead of via the asset pipeline. Then I also had to change the selector to grab the link directly by the id instead of via the container div. Not ideal but it seems to work for now. I can only assume the bootstrap js version I had was outdated?

Comment: make sure that bootstrap.js is loaded after jquery.js